# How to remove attribute from session using Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, session, thymeleaf

Somewhere in my code, I'm adding an attribute into the session.

```
session.setAttribute("message", message);
```

And in my HTML file, I want to remove it right after I comsume it.

```
<div th:if="${session.message != null}">
   // consume message
   // remove message from session.
</div>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You can't... instead, you should use flash attributes in cases like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44488706/4126893 -- they'll disappear for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Created a component with this method.

```
public void removeVerificationMessageFromSession() {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.removeAttribute("verificationMessage");
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            log.error("No Request: ", ex);
        }
    }
```

and then I called this method in my code right after I consumed the message.

```
<div th:if="${session.message != null}">
   // I consumed the message
   <div th:text="${@sessionUtilityBean.removeVerificationMessageFromSession()}"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used

```
 <th:block th:inline="text"> [[${#session.removeAttribute('variableName')}]]</th:block>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used

**and create a helper class**

```
@Component
public class SessionHelper {
    
    public void removeMessageFromSession() {
        try {
            System.out.println("removing message form session ");
            HttpSession session = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getSession();
            session.removeAttribute("message");
            
            
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div th:if="${session.message}" th:classappend="${session.message.type}" class="alert">

<p th:text="${session.message.content}"></p>

<th:block th:text="${@sessionHelper.removeMessageFromSession()}"></th:block>
                            
</div>
```

Comment: this is only for thymeleaf 3.1.1 version and uper version

Comment: It supports Jakarta