# Display an alert-info after redirecting to login page in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, redirect, thymeleaf, registration

I have an application in Spring Boot.

I want to create a "registration succesful" alert after redirecting from the registration page to the login page, but I don't know how to create alert-info on the login page.

I already have 2 messages about logout and error:

```
<!-- error message -->
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">wrong email or password</div>
</div>

<!-- logout message -->
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    <div class="alert alert-info">Logout</div>
</div>
```

And for example I want to get to the login page after registering by:

```
return "redirect:/Login?success";
```

and get this:

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751860/how-to-set-a-flash-message-in-spring-boot-with-thymeleaf

Comment: that's what i was looking for, thank you