# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#session.removeAttribute('message')"

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-framework-beans

I'm getting exception when trying to evaluate a thymeleaf expression. The html code & error is as below. Please do let me know why session.removeAttribute is not working here.

```
HTML-


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    th:replace="base::layout(~{::section})">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>This is About page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
         <div class="registration-card mt-1">
       <div th:if="${session.message}"
        th:classappend="${session.message.type}" class="alert">
       <p class="text-center" th:text="${session.message.content}"></p>
       <th:block th:text="${#session.removeAttribute('message')}"></th:block>

        </div>
        <div class="container text-center">
    <img style="width: 50px" src="" th:src="@{/img/sign-up.png}"alt="" />
    </div>
    <h1 class="text-center" style="text-decoration-line: underline;">RegisterHere</h1>
    <form th:action="@{/do_register}" method="post" th:object="${user}">

     <!-- Name -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"          placeholder="Enter Your Name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" th:value="${user.name}" required>
    </div>

    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label> <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
    placeholder="Enter Your Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" th:value="${user.email}" required>
    </div>
    
        <!-- Button -->
    <div class="container text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-primary text-white">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</button>
    </div>
      </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Exception-

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#session.removeAttribute('message')" (template: "signup" - line 17, col 18)

Comment: Why are you using `session.removeAttribute` ? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to remove the error/success msg which comes after clicking on submit button

Comment: What you want is a "flash message", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751860/how-to-set-a-flash-message-in-spring-boot-with-thymeleaf for more information on how to do that.

Comment: Above one is not working for me...can u pls suggest any other step

Answer (score 0):

```html
<th:block th:text="${#session.removeAttribute('message')}"></th:block>
```

remove this or comment this line from ur code it will work

Comment: Yes code will work but I want to remove the error/success msg which comes after clicking on submit button